# Check hours from one day to another in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, which has columns to store the start time and end of the service (I do not have date and time, only the day of the week). I have to check if a time is available for the week, considering that a service starts on Monday and ends on Tuesday. Can someone help me?

```
CREATE TABLE #Calendar (
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    DayWeek INT,
    HourStart TIME,
    HourEnd TIME
);

INSERT INTO #Calendar (Name, DayWeek, HourStart, HourEnd)
    VALUES ('Make a Cake', 1, '19:00:00', '07:00:00');

INSERT INTO #Calendar (Name, DayWeek, HourStart, HourEnd)
    VALUES ('Make a cookie', 1, '07:00:00', '19:00:00');

INSERT INTO #Calendar (Name, DayWeek, HourStart, HourEnd)
    VALUES ('Make a cookie', 2, '19:00:00', '23:00:00');
```

Comment: Can you clarify the " I have to check if a time is available for the week, considering that a service starts on Monday and ends on Tuesday" part? Maybe with an example?

Comment: Day 1 (Monday) is already occupied from "7:00 PM" to "7:00 AM" on day 2 (Tuesday). I have to do a "select" to check if I can insert a new line with time "20:00" to "22:00", I could not enter this new line, since that period is busy. I tried to use between, I could not. Can you understand?

Comment: so what you actually mean is that HourStart goes to DayWeek, while HourEnd goes to DayWeek+1. And you want to check if you can input a new line without hour overlappings, right?

Comment: Yes, I need to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve it. It will not be able to use index because it uses calculation on columns when comparing:

```
DECLARE @from time = '22:59', @to time = '23:01'

DECLARE @DayWeek int = 2

;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT 
  dateadd(d, @DayWeek, cast(@from as datetime)) startdate,
  dateadd(d, 
    CASE WHEN @to < @from 
         THEN @DayWeek + 1
         ELSE @DayWeek
    END,
  cast(@to as datetime)) enddate
)
SELECT CASE WHEN 
not exists
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM #Calendar c 
  WHERE cte.startdate < dateadd(d, CASE WHEN HourEnd < HourStart 
  THEN DayWeek + 1 ELSE DayWeek END, cast(HourEnd as datetime))
  AND cte.enddate > dateadd(d, DayWeek, cast(HourEnd as datetime))
) THEN 'Available' ELSE 'Not available' END
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

OK, this must work. It shows every line which has a time conflict; if you uncomment the last where it will show lines without conflict too

```
declare @test_DateTimeStart datetime=dateadd(day,4,'20:00:00') -- Check from Monday 20:00
declare @test_DateTimeEnd datetime=dateadd(day,5,'20:00:00') -- Check to Tuesday 20:00

select q2.result,c.*
from 
    #Calendar c
    cross apply 
    (   select 
        dateadd(day,DayWeek,convert(datetime,HourStart)) as DateTimeStart,
        dateadd(day,DayWeek+1,convert(datetime,HourEnd)) as DateTimeEnd
    )q
    cross apply (select
        case when exists
        (
            select 1 from #Calendar c2 where 
                (@test_DateTimeStart>DateTimeStart and @test_DateTimeStart<DateTimeEnd)
                or
                (@test_DateTimeEnd  >DateTimeStart and @test_DateTimeEnd  <DateTimeEnd)
        )
        then 'Time is taken due to this row -->'
        else 'Time is free due to this row -->'
        end as result
    )q2
--where result='Time is taken due to this row -->'
```

Comment: is it HH:MM:SS format? then why difference of 100 between tuesday & monday?

Comment: I'm just adding the day number in front of the string. Since he uses 0-padding, the order will be correct.

Comment: I could not make it work, I believe it is incompatible in this line: "convert (nvarchar (max), Dayweek) + HourStart to DateTimeStart," because my column is of type "TIME"

"The nvarchar (max) and hour data types are incompatible in the add operator."

Comment: oh, what datatypes are the fields DayWeek, HourStart, HourEnd? I thought they were text

Comment: DayWeek INT, HourStart TIME and HourEnd TIME

Comment: Check it out now (Funksoul brother)

Comment: I tested this script. I am getting some really funky results. When only having 1 row in the calendar: day-1 from-19:00 to-20:00. I tested 21:00-22:00 same day and was told it was taken

Comment: As Joe said, the end time corresponds to the NEXT day - thus, your 19-20 means Monday 19:00 to Tuesday 20:00, which of course includes your test range.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code to get the current day of week real time. then compare with your save data

```
var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

var response = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

string todaysDates = response.Headers["date"];

return  DateTime.ParseExact(todaysDates,"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'GMT'",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal).DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: I'm using sql only, and I can not access a sql webservice :(